# Uso e significato di "essere colto d'amore" e espressioni simili

Tags: word-usage, meaning

Nel racconto *Argon* dal libro *Il sistema periodico*, di Primo Levi, ho letto (grassetto mio):

> Ora avvenne che sua madre, la zia Milca («Regina»), si ammalò, e dopo molto contendere col marito si indusse ad accettare di assumere una havertà, ossia una domestica, cosa che aveva recisamente rifiutata fino a quel tempo: infatti, presaga, non voleva donne per casa. Puntualmente, Barbabramín **fu colto d’amore** per questa havertà, probabilmente la prima femmina meno che santa che gli fosse stato dato di avvicinare.

Posso più o meno immaginare il significato di "essere colto d'amore", anche se si tratta di un'espressione che non ho trovato su nessun dizionario. È d'uso comune?

E, riguardo al significato, c'è una sfumatura di qualcosa che accade all'improvviso? Cioè, dovrei capire che Barbabramín non si era poco a poco innamorato di questa "havertà", ma il suo innamoramento era arrivato improvvisamente? O significa semplicemente "innamorarsi"?

Si può anche dire "essere colto da" + un altro sentimento?

Comment: È la preposizione “da”, raramente apostrofata al giorno d'oggi.

Comment: Ah, grazie, @egreg: ho corretto il post.

Comment: "Colto da collera (improvvisa)”, per esempio.

Comment: Sicuramente un uso letterario, non comune. Un uso  più comune è quello di *essere colto da un malore,* di solito improvvisamente.

Comment: @egreg: Anche "colto da gelosia", no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La preposizione “da” si apostrofa di rado al giorno d’oggi, ma non è “vietato”. È ancora frequente in strutture cristallizzate come *d’ora in poi*.

Il verbo è *fu colto*, quindi passato remoto passivo e non può reggere altro che *da* per il soggetto logico.<sup>1</sup>

Si può essere colti da *amore*, *collera*, *gelosia* e tanto altro. Il verbo è passivo, a significare che è lo stato d'animo “personificato” che coglie, cioè afferra, svelle o solleva. Pertanto contiene certamente l'idea di qualcosa che accade all'improvviso.

---

<sup>1</sup>  Ciò che compie l'azione, altrimenti detto complemento d'agente o di causa efficiente. Con una distinzione che in italiano non ha alcun senso, ma è nelle grammatiche perché in latino si usano modi distinti se il soggetto logico è una persona o una cosa.

Answer (score 2):

Il senso è quello di una cosa improvvisa, inattesa. Treccani.it usa l’espressione “colto da” come sinonimo di sorpreso:

[Sorpreso:](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/sorpreso_%28Sinonimi-e-Contrari%29/)

> 1. [con valore verbale, ***colto all'improvviso,*** anche fig.: un pregiudicato sorpreso 
>      a rubare; malattia sorpresa all'inizio] ≈ (fam.) beccato, colto, preso.
> 2. [***colto da meraviglia*** dinanzi a qualcosa di inatteso o fuori
>      dell'ordinario] ≈ meravigliato, stupito. ↑ allibito, esterrefatto,
>      strabiliato, stupefatto, [solo in funz. predicativa] (fam.) a bocca
>      aperta, [solo in funz. predicativa] senza parole (mi ha lasciato senza
>      parole).